# AJAX login without a plugin does not work. when add a action to function.php

Tags: plugins, functions, ajax, login, actions

I am using wordpress ajax login without a plugin.

I want to not be allowed users access to the WordPress profile after login, Because i have designed a specific profile in the link: `http://www.domain.com/profile`. That's why I use the following code. When I add the following code to function.php. The AJAX login does not work.

```
  // Redirect user to profile.php page 
add_action('init' , 'prevent_profile_access');
function prevent_profile_access(){
    if (current_user_can('manage_options')) return '';

    if (strpos($_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'] , 'wp-admin' )){
        wp_redirect ("http://www.domain.com/profile");
    }
    if (strpos($_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'] , 'wp-login.php' )){
        wp_redirect ("http://www.domain.com/profile");
    }
}
```

How do I solve this problem?

My AJAX login codes:

HTML:

```
<form id="login" action="login" method="post">
    <h1>Site Login</h1>
    <p class="status"></p>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="password">
    <a class="lost" href="<?php echo wp_lostpassword_url(); ?>">Lost your password?</a>
    <input class="submit_button" type="submit" value="Login" name="submit">
    <a class="close" href="">(close)</a>
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' ); ?>
</form>
```

PHP(function.php):

```
    function ajax_login_init(){

        wp_register_script('ajax-login-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/ajax-login-script.js', array('jquery') ); 
        wp_enqueue_script('ajax-login-script');

        wp_localize_script( 'ajax-login-script', 'ajax_login_object', array( 
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'redirecturl' => home_url(),
            'loadingmessage' => __('Sending user info, please wait...')
        ));

        // Enable the user with no privileges to run ajax_login() in AJAX
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin', 'ajax_login' );
    }

    // Execute the action only if the user isn't logged in
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        add_action('init', 'ajax_login_init');
    }
function ajax_login(){

    // First check the nonce, if it fails the function will break
    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-login-nonce', 'security' );

    // Nonce is checked, get the POST data and sign user on
    $info = array();
    $info['user_login'] = $_POST['username'];
    $info['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
    $info['remember'] = true;

    $user_signon = wp_signon( $info, false );
    if ( is_wp_error($user_signon) ){
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>false, 'message'=>__('Wrong username or password.')));
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('loggedin'=>true, 'message'=>__('Login successful, redirecting...')));
    }

    die();
}
```

AJAX(ajax-login-script.js):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // Show the login dialog box on click
    $('a#show_login').on('click', function(e){
        $('body').prepend('<div class="login_overlay"></div>');
        $('form#login').fadeIn(500);
        $('div.login_overlay, form#login a.close').on('click', function(){
            $('div.login_overlay').remove();
            $('form#login').hide();
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Perform AJAX login on form submit
    $('form#login').on('submit', function(e){
        $('form#login p.status').show().text(ajax_login_object.loadingmessage);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: ajax_login_object.ajaxurl,
            data: { 
                'action': 'ajaxlogin', //calls wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxlogin
                'username': $('form#login #username').val(), 
                'password': $('form#login #password').val(), 
                'security': $('form#login #security').val() },
            success: function(data){
                $('form#login p.status').text(data.message);
                if (data.loggedin == true){
                    document.location.href = ajax_login_object.redirecturl;
                }
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook it later.

```
add_action('template_redirect' , 'prevent_profile_access');
```

References:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect

Comment: This "did you try to hook it later" is always dangerous and leads to a lot of issues. Always, always. Go deep to see when you need to hook / why, otherwise things break.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @coolpasta ! I changed my words to indicate a command.